# error indexing a list within a list to create database columns sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

this is probably something basic that i am missing but its doing my head in, if you can help that would be much appreciated.
I have a list of lists that are basically meant to be my sqlite3 database columns:

```
vars= [['TRANSACTION_KEY', 'VARCHAR(28)'], ['CARD_KEY', 'VARCHAR(12)'], ['STORE_KEY', 'VARCHAR(4)'], ['PRODUCT_KEY', 'VARCHAR(18)'], ['TRX_DATE', 'VARCHAR(10)'], ['UMB', 'VARCHAR(4)'], ['TRX_TIME', 'VARCHAR(8)'], ['QUANTITY', 'REAL'], ['SPEND_AMOUNT', 'REAL'], ['EAN', 'VARCHAR(13)'], ['UMV', 'VARCHAR(4)'], ['FC', 'REAL']] <type 'list'>
```

I want to convert these to a tuple of strings to allow concatenating with a sqlite3 CREATE TABLE statement:

```
(STORE_KEY VARCHAR(4),
UMV VARCHAR(4),
EAN VARCHAR(13),
TRANSACTION_KEY VARCHAR(28),
TRX_DATE VARCHAR(10),
PRODUCT_KEY VARCHAR(18),
SPEND_AMOUNT REAL,
FC REAL,
TRX_TIME VARCHAR(8),
CARD_KEY VARCHAR(12),
UMB VARCHAR(4),
QUANTITY REAL)
```

this is the code I am using

```
columns = "(" + ",\n".join("{} {}".format(i[0],i[1]) for i in vars) + ")"
```

but I keep getting the exact same output:

```
database columns:  [['TRANSACTION_KEY', 'VARCHAR(28)'], ['CARD_KEY', 'VARCHAR(12)'], ['STORE_KEY', 'VARCHAR(4)'], ['PRODUCT_KEY', 'VARCHAR(18)'], ['TRX_DATE', 'VARCHAR(10)'], ['UMB', 'VARCHAR(4)'], ['TRX_TIME', 'VARCHAR(8)'], ['QUANTITY', 'REAL'], ['SPEND_AMOUNT', 'REAL'], ['EAN', 'VARCHAR(13)'], ['UMV', 'VARCHAR(4)'], ['FC', 'REAL']]
```

so something must be wrong when I try to index the individuals elements of each list within the vars list, can you please help?? many thanks!

Comment: @MByD thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. Did you try `print(columns)` command ?

here is what I am getting

[image]

Comment: thanks @Vikash Singh, I rewrote the function and in the end managed to move forward, that said I will revisit this and try to replicate your results, thanks so much for your help, much appreciated!